# How to provide template for particular view mode?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I want to theme the search result view mode with a template.

I had it in my head that naming a template file node--article--search-result.tpl.php would do the trick, but I'm obviously wrong about that.

I realise I can do node--article.tpl.php and within this check $view_mode, but this is awkward with all the other view modes that I don't want to template.

Ideas?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Adding theme hook suggestions in a node preprocess function should do the trick:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'article' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'search_result') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__article__search_result';
  }
}
```

After clearing the caches you should be able to use node--article--search-result.tpl.php for your template file name.

NB. You could also do this in your theme's template.php file by calling the function `MYTHEME_preprocess_node()` instead.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Was just about to add a link to same advice here: http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes

Comment: No problem :) Just FYI, `search_result` is already declared as a view mode so you don't need to implement `hook_entity_info_alter()` in your case

Answer (score 3):

The [Entity view modes](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) module adds these template suggestions automatically

> The Drupal 7 successor to [Build modes](http://drupal.org/project/buildmodes) which will allow administrators to define custom view modes for entities. Custom entities are added to the entity registry via hook_entity_info_alter() so they are available to any code that uses entity_get_info() to provide a list of view modes for an entity. This includes node and user reference fields, Views, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that allows you to add new ones dynamically. It also calls the corresponding preprocess function if you have one declared.

Then call `drush cache-clear theme-registry` to get it working.

To use it replace THEME with your theme's name, and place it in your themes template.php file.

e.g. For a theme named Droid you would call it `droid_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {`...

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
  $view_mode = $variables['view_mode'];
  $content_type = $variables['type'];
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $view_mode;
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $view_mode . '_' . $content_type;

  $view_mode_preprocess = 'THEME_preprocess_node_' . $view_mode . '_' . $content_type;
  if (function_exists($view_mode_preprocess)) {
    $view_mode_preprocess($variables, $hook);
  }

  $view_mode_preprocess = 'THEME_preprocess_node_' . $view_mode;
  if (function_exists($view_mode_preprocess)) {
    $view_mode_preprocess($variables, $hook);
  }
}
```