# Custom tpl for view mode for all contenty type

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I've saw [How to provide template for particular view mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27025/how-to-provide-template-for-particular-view-mode), but I don't to create a single tpl for every content type for a particular view mode, but a tpl used for every content type for a particular view_mode, something like node--search-results.tpl.php

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, just add the following code to your theme's template.php file (replacing `MYTHEME` with the name of your theme):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $vars['view_mode'];
}
```

And remember to clear the caches