# Is it possible to create a template (tpl) file for comment view mode?

Tags: 7, theming

I created a new view mode for **comments** called "cool", as shown in the image below (click the image for full size):

[image]

I created **comment--cool.tpl.php** and added it to my theme template folder.

Based on the question about [Custom tpl for view mode for all contenty type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58007/custom-tpl-for-view-mode-for-all-contenty-type), I also need to add a pre-process to my theme. I tried:

```
  function MyThemeName_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'comment__' . $vars['view_mode'];
  }
```

But I get an error "Undefined index: view_mode"

Seems like comments preprocess doesn't have view_mode as an argument. So I guess it's not possible to create a tpl for comments? OR is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With take look at  [Template Comment Preprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7) You find out that you just need use  `$vars['elements']['#view_mode']` instead of `$vars['view_mode']`.