# How to wrap node output with a link using Display Suite?

Tags: theming, display-suite

how would I best wrap my entire node in an  tag linking to the full node? My nodes are display using Display Suite and a custom view mode.

I'm guessing creating a php template and manually writing the link somehow would work?

Comment: One thing to note: what you are proposing is valid in HTML 5 but not in HTML 4 or earlier (assuming your node output includes div and other block level elements). Otherwise you can certainly do this with a custom template. This answer might help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27025/how-to-provide-template-for-particular-view-mode

Comment: Yes, would need to use the <!doctype html> - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go `/admin/structure/types/manage/blog/display/teaser` (or whatever content type you're going for) at the bottom is a list of possible template names. In my example `ds-2col-stacked-fluid--node.tpl.php` was what I needed.

In the template file I ended up wrapping my content variables with the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo url('node/' . $nid); ?>"> normal node here </a>
```

One thing to note is that you need to make sure there are no nested links around fields like image, author or title.

Answer (score 7):

A good option for this is [Field Group Link](http://drupal.org/project/field_group_link).

For your case, basically you need to create a field group wrapping the whole node, and set the group type to 'Link'.

Comment: great site builder resource there!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a display suite custom wrapper.

Make sure you are using a display suite layout for the teaser view mode, and then select custom wrappers from the bottom left hand menu. Choose "link to content" from the "add link" drop down.