# Print a node display mode in a tpl file

Tags: 7, theming

I have a switch statement in my content type tpl file for 2 different view modes:

```
<?php 
switch ($view_mode) {
case 'full' :
?>

//content for full view mode here

<?php break;
case 'custom-display-mode' : ?>

//content for custom display mode view mode here

<?php break;                
} ?>
```

How can I print the teaser view mode within full display mode? Can I print it out in the same way you can print fileds in a tpl file?

```
<?php 
switch ($view_mode) {
case 'full' :
?>

//content for full view mode here
//********* also print teaser view mode here **********

<?php break;
case 'custom-display-mode' : ?>

//content for custom display mode view mode here

<?php break;                
} ?>
```

Comment: This is so illogical it doesnt make sense. Revise your strategy...

Comment: The teaser view only shows a few fields and styles them in a custom way. Its used by a view and I also need it to appear in a section in the default node page. So whats illogical about that...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to print full display mode + teaser mode under full display mode? You can always render any display mode directly using [node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) as

> node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL)

or with your example:

```
switch ($view_mode) {
case 'full' :

//content for full view mode here

$rendered_teaser = render(node_view(node_load($nid), 'teaser'));
print $rendered_teaser;

...
```

I would also recommend breaking your [display mode templates out into separate files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27025/how-to-provide-template-for-particular-view-mode) to simplify management. If your full mode should be the same as your teaser then using this method you can always just symbolically link the files on your server.