# How can I embed a node inside on another node?

Tags: 7, nodes

In Drupal 7 I have a content type created by admin (say content type X), And the other part i have a content type created by users (say content type Y).
Now that is what I do when a user creates content type Y, he can select a node of content-type X to embed node x in node Y.

Without link title node by "References Module" or coding html by "node_embed Module".

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Your question is not quite clear. Can you try to re-phrase it to make it easier to understand what you want and where you fail? Also, please include information about what you have already tried or what resources you have used so far to try to solve your problem. This will make it easier for others here to provide an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [entityreference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) together with [display suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) and have the display of the entityreference field set to rendered entity. Using rendered entities you can can render any entity with a view mode you need for your display. See this question if you want to create a custom template for the output of that node: [How to provide template for particular view mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27025/how-to-provide-template-for-particular-view-mode)

Comment: AFAIK entity reference or node reference should be just fine. You don't need the quite heavy Display Suite for that.