# Catch first node in a view template

Tags: views, theming

I created a view for the front page and also a node--view--frontpage.html.twig to design this view. Is there any opportunity to catch the first node with a if statement to design it differently?

In this case I want to change the order of the first iteration in the `node--view--frontpage.html.twig`:

```
{% set createdDate = node.getCreatedTime | date('j.m.Y') %}
<article{{ attributes }}>
  {{ content.field_picture }}
  <div class="meta">
    {{ createdDate }}
    {% if content.typ | render | trim %}
      , {{ content.typ }}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <h2 class="news" {{ title_attributes }}>
    <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
  </h2>
  {{ content.body }}
</article>
```

Comment: You should elaborate your question further more. Please paste the relevant code that you've so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [display suite module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) has a views integration that allows you to choose a different display mode for the first node in a view versus all the others. In this case you can easily create a [separate tpl for that view mode](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27025/how-to-provide-template-for-particular-view-mode) and you're good to go. Its extremely powerful. Take a look at [this post](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/display-suite-views/) and look for "Alternating view modes" in the last screen shot.